# SwiftUI - STPAddCardViewController is not showing billing address

Tags: swift, swiftui, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement Add Payment Method with Stripe in SwiftUI. The code works fine but it does not display the field for user Billing address. This is my code

```
struct AddCardView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
   @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
 
  //     @ObservedObject var model: PaymentMethodViewModel
 
 func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
     let controller = STPAddCardViewController()
     controller.delegate = context.coordinator
     controller.edgesForExtendedLayout = .all
     let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
     navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
     return navigationController
 }
 
 func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController, context: Context) {
     
 }
 
 func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
     Coordinator(self)
 }
     
 class Coordinator: NSObject, STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
     var parent: AddCardView
     
     func addCardViewControllerDidCancel(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController) {
         parent.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
     }
     
     func addCardViewController(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
         print(paymentMethod)
    //             parent.model.isCards = true
         parent.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
     }
     
     init(_ parent: AddCardView) {
         self.parent = parent
     }
  }
 }
```

the code above produces this

[image]

I thought the Billing information text field will be included in the STPAddCardViewController method like this image

[image]

How can fix the code above to include text field for users to enter the card billing address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a configuration and a theme in your initialize method.
Here is sample in Objective-C.

```
STPPaymentConfiguration *configuration = [[STPPaymentConfiguration alloc] init];
configuration.requiredBillingAddressFields = STPBillingAddressFieldsFull;
STPAddCardViewController *addCardVC = [[STPAddCardViewController alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration theme:[STPTheme defaultTheme]];
addCardVC.alwaysEnableDoneButton = YES;
addCardVC.delegate = self;
vc = addCardVC;
```

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/591f54d11f6f60be609e294f7dd7570c0ad32b49/LocalizationTester/ViewController.m

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I said in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you could try using "STPPaymentConfiguration" parameters, and call

```
let controller = STPAddCardViewController(configuration: ... , theme: ...)
```